# Como limitar o número de linhas de uma tabela HTML

Tags: php, html

Estou fazendo uma tela de listagem do banco de dados e mostrando os resultados em uma tabela HTML, está tudo funcionando, mas gostaria de limitar o número de linhas exibidas em cinco para ficar tudo na mesma tela e a rolagem seja feita na própria tabela. Segue o código:

```
 <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>#</th>
                      <th>Nome</th>
                      <th>E_mail</th>
                      <th>Tipo</th>
                      <th>Opções</th>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                   <?php  while($reg=$listar->fetch_array()){
                   echo "<tr>";
                      echo "<td>".$reg['id_usuario']."</td>
                      <td>".$reg['nome_professor']."</td>
                      <td>".$reg['nome_usuario']."</td>
                      <td>".$reg['tipo']."</td>
                      <td>
                      <a class='btn btn-primary'  name='deletar'><i class='fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-times-circle-o text-danger'></i></a>
                      </td>
                      <td><a class='btn btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-edit fa-fw fa-lg'></i></a> </td>";
                    "</tr>";
                     }
                      ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Uma alternativa simples seria adicionar o conteúdo dentro de um iframe, limitar o tamanho dele e colocar a barra de rolagem dentro dele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa necessariamente se preocupar com o número de linhas, e sim com o tamanho máximo que sua tabela pode ter. É possível definir um tamanho máximo ao corpo da tabela e se esse limite for ultrapassado adicionar uma barra de rolagem, fiz um exemplo rápido aqui, veja se atende a sua necessidade:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        table, td, th {
            border: solid 1px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        thead, tbody {
            display: block;
            width: 130px;
        }
        tbody {
            height: 200px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Coluna 1</th>
                <th>Coluna 2</th>                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++): ?>
            <tr>
                <td>Valor 1</td>
                <td>Valor 2</td>
            </tr>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```